# How to activate disk spill on Presto

Tags: presto

Hello im string to activate spill to disk on presto 0.167, when i enter in presto i run "SET SESSION spill_enabled=true;" but whatever i run next it gives the message "spill_enabled cannot be set to true; no spill paths configured".
In the official Teradata to enable the spill it should be done the comand "beta.spill-enabled", which didnt work. to define a spill path should be "beta.spiller-spill-path" which doesnt work as well.

Here is the official Teradata Presto Properties page:
https://teradata.github.io/presto/docs/current/admin/properties.html#properties-controlling-spilling

Can someone provide some help on this subject?

Comment: "to define a spill path should be "beta.spiller-spill-path" which doesnt work as well." -- what did not work? `beta.spiller-spill-path = /some/dir1, /some/dir2` should go into `config.properties`, it's a config, not a command.

Comment: Also, what exact version are you using? "0.167" is not precise enough.

Comment: the presto version is 0.167-T.0.2. Ill try to do the path in config.properties.

Comment: i added the beta.spiller-spill-path  property in config.properties. Adding like beta.spiller-spill-path = /data/spill i cant start presto, so i tried with the path between " " and ' ' but when i try to enable the spill in presto (with SET SESSION spill_enabled=true) i get the same error "spill_enabled cannot be set to true; no spill paths configured"

Comment: `beta.spiller-spill-path = /data/spill` looks good. What exception are you getting? Also, use latest version (.0.6 i think)

Answer (score -1):

Documentation can be found [here](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/admin/properties.html#spilling-properties).

the `spill-enabled` property is prefixed with `experimental`. So, it should be `experimental.spill-enabled`. Also, when that is enabled, `spiller-spill-path` cannot be empty. So, that is why it's complaining `no spill paths configured`.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, there is a catch.
The in-flight setting up of the  SET SESSION spill_enabled=true would fail with error *Session property spill_path does not exist*

Your `etc/config.properties` file should contain

```
experimental.spiller-spill-path='/mnt/tmp/'
```

then you can setup on the fly.

```
SET SESSION spill_enabled=true
```